# Why a yii component works on localhost and not on remote server?

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I am working with yii and i have set up the component langBox.

when i try to use it on my localhost it works while when i try using it on my remote server i get the following error;

```
CException
     Alias "application.components.langBox" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.
```

any ideas or tips will be most appreciated

Comment: Like the error says, check that the file is in application/components/langBox, and that whatever is running it (likely Apache) has read permissions to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are developing in windows and deploying your app on linux, remember that linux filesystem is case sensitive. For instance on linux `LangBox` is **not** the same as `langBox`. Make sure that your alias has exact same case as in filename in filesystem.

Comment: ohh yeah , i keep on forgetting , thanks as soon as i get home i will try it